Why can't I login on PuTTY?

I started learning Linux last night. Login as root works fine, but login for regular user says access denied. Why? It worked last night when I created it.

What is the distribution you use? And in most distributions direct login with root is not permitted. You should login as ordinary user and then su or sudo

I use putty. Thanks for the assist.

Here's how it happened. I open my putty app, load the file i want to open then enter my ip address. Then it asks for my password, I enter the password then access denied. I dont know why...

Have you changed your password? Is your username in the group that is allowed to access SSH (look for sshd.conf)?

Is there a system administrator for the server you're trying to login to? They should be able to help you with password issues. It also would be best if you switched to public key-based authentication.

no i haven't changed my password. I'm new to all of this like a newborn to life itself. I made my password through linode and it worked yesterday. Have any of you ever used linode? then putty then had this problem the next day?

no system admin either. Just me creating a server on linode for practice using a system i've never used before. I want to understand it and get good at it for a career I want.

I'm learning from the linux handbook now and a few other guides and i'll report back on my progress.

In order to log in instead of getting "permission denied" you must enter a login name and password that exist on the remote server.  Either the login name is not valid (because it doesn't exist or the remote system doesn't accept it because it is in the wrong format) or the password is wrong or the system is not configured to accept passwords from ssh.

More often than not, you just need to Open your "ssh_config" File (under "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"), then simply Uncomment (Remove the Hash Character from) the following line and Save your Changes.
#PasswordAuthentication yes
Afterwards, Run the following Command to Restart the SSH Service (assuming you're running a Debian-based linux Distro, like Ubuntu, etc.).
sudo systemctl restart sshd

If you continue to experience problems, it may be the Permissions on your "authorized_keys" File. You'll want to start in your "home" Folder.
cd /home/<Username>

If necessary you may have to Update the Permissions, as follows.
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Feel free to report back with your results, as I have some additional troubleshooting steps, if neither of the aforementioned options work for you.
